# Como compara o ultimo carácter de uma string com alguma letra ou acento

Tags: c#

Estou Precisando comparar a ultimá letra de uma String com um acento de interrogação.

Eu já fiz e o código funciona, só que estou pegando a ultima letra com `Substring`, usando `Length` e está um código até feio.

Eu quero saber se existe alguma função para fazer essa comparação de uma forma mais simples ou seja, específica para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
    var minhaString = "Qual o último char?";

    if (minhaString.EndsWith("?"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("O último char é '?'");
    }
```

Aqui está rodando no [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vqfQzG)